# Probability of event happening

Tags: probability, self-study

> Let $p$ denote the probability that a firm fiddles its books. Suppose that $p = 0.1$ . Also suppose that a financial professional services firm keeps auditing firms until they have found 3 ‘bad’ ones.
>
> Compute the probability that they will need to audit exactly 6 firms.

My answer is $$6C3\times(0.1)^3\times(0.9)^3\approx0.01458$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get exactly 2 `F`s among the first five firms audited; then the *last* one must be the third `F`.

So it's ${5\choose 2}(.1)^3(.9)^3 =0.00729$ or,
for number $X$ of `F`s in $n=5$ audits, its $(0.1)P(X=2, 5, .1) = 0.00729.$
[In R.]

```
choose(5,2)*.1^3*.9^3
[1] 0.00729
dbinom(2, 5, .1)*.1
[1] 0.00729
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of negative binomial distribution. X~NBD(3,0.1)

X: No of failures before r<sup>th</sup> (6) success.

$$P(X=3) = 5C2 \times (0.1)^3 \times (0.1)^3 = 7.29 \times 10^{-3}. $$

Hope this helps.
Also, out of curiosity, are you applying for the MSBA program at imperial ?